# What is the formal mathematical expression to denote the division of an integer n until n satisfies a condition?

Tags: summation, algorithms, divisibility

For example, extracting the first digit of an integer *n* requires dividing *n* by 10 until *n* < 10.

Is there a symbol, expression, or formula to express this operation in mathematics in a concise manner similar to summation notation? If so, what would that be?

Comment: You could divide by $10^{k-1}$ , where $k$ is the number of digits and apply the floor function, but better is to calculate the decade logarithm and then take the fractional part $f$. Then $10^f$ shows the first digits. I am not aware of a name for the first digit of a number. This is usually formulated out although mathematicians abbreviate almost everything.

Answer (score 1):

Let a sequence of digits be given as $d_k = \lfloor n / 10^k \rfloor$

Let the most significant digit be indexed as $m = \max_k d_k \ne 0$

Then $d_m$ refers to the most significant digit.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't bring any common computer science operations into the picture, say [unbounded search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C_operator), then a formalization denoting the first rational of the form ${n}/d^k$ with a given property $P$ and $k$ implict, would be

$\mathrm{max}_{>_{\mathbb Q}} \left\{q\ \in\  \mathrm{range}\left[\left(k\colon{\mathbb N}\right)\mapsto \left({n}/d^k\colon{\mathbb Q}\right)\right]\ \mid\  P(q) \right\}$

This considers the decreasing function mapping any $k$ to the fraction $\frac{n}{d^k}$. It takes the range of that function, giving the set of all return values at once. It then filters this set of rational numbers using set comprehension, using the property $P$. It finally selects the maximum with respect to the standard order on the rationals, giving you the first value with the property $P$. Equivalently to comprehension, you could intersect the function range with all rationals for which $P$ holds. The expression will look nicer if you define the function seperately.